# Any problems running SharpDevelop 3.0 and Visual Studio 2008 side by side?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I have been asked to lend a hand on a hobby project that a couple friends are working on, they are using SharpDevelop 3.0 (Beta 2 I think, but it might be Beta 1) is there any hassle for me to install and use this IDE given that I have Visual Studio 2008 installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had no problems at all, in fact some of the tools in sharpdevelop (like the vb.net -> c# converter) are very nice to have.

In addition, there are some good libraries included with sharpdevelop that are also handy (like sharpziplib for zip files)

I actually have VS2005, VS2008, SharpDevelop and VisualStudio 6 installed at the moment, and there's more compat problems with MS's tools than with #develop.

Answer (score 2):

They behave very well together, I have had SharpDevelop installed with 2003, 2005 and 2008. No issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had SharpDevelop installed for a while but when I did the only problem I ran in to was that I couldn't easily share the solution file. If you don't mind having two different solutions there should be no problems.